# How to quickly migrate from SVN to Git?

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn

We have a business requirement to migrate an existing code repository from SVN to Git.

However, the only option put forward by our SVN Administrative Team, a command line solution, appears not to be ideal as the timescale proposed is too prolonged, excessive and not acceptable or suitable.

What I'd therefore be grateful for is advise on an alternative solution which isn't only effective, but one that can also be completed in a relatively short time.

Comment: We're still not interested in whether your work is urgent. I've mentioned this to you twice already, on your prior questions, and you still seem to think hurrying volunteers will aid you. I doubt it will. It is generally thought to be rude or overly entitled to ask volunteers for special treatment.

Comment: Your accept and reply rate is extremely low - it looks like you have asked 24 questions and accepted two. While it is not mandatory to accept questions, it is also unusual for that many questions to not get replies, and some answers you have received have not been replied to at all. That will not encourage people to help you in the future.

Comment: Note also that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: @halfer, I appreciate your feedback and if any of my posts breach any rules on Stackoverflow, then I render a sincere apology. However, I beg to differ on some of the issues of concern you've raised. Firstly, I do not believe that describing my predicament or query as an urgent need is in any case hurrying or forcing volunteers to assist. As described by yourself, any contribution on this forum is volunteered and not enforced or mandatory, I therefore fail to see how describing my need as urgent is either rude or forceful. Sorry, but I don't agree one bit with that assertion.

Comment: It is the [community's view](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569). You can come to _Meta_ to argue the opposite case if you wish, but I can assure you any such action will be very unpopular.

Answer (score 3):

Try https://subgit.com/ it allows use existing svn repo by regular svn user access, i.e. does not require direct admin access to the svn repo. And also allows simultaneous work and synchronisation between both repos during migration period.